# Display all online users in a Slack channel

Tags: slack-api, slack

New to slack at the moment - I've looked around to see if there's a Slack command to show all online users in a Slack channel but haven't found any.

Would a custom slack command calling a Slack API method eg. users.getPresence be the way to go or is there another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet would be to first retrieve the list of members within the channel using the Web API method [channels.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.info).

Each `channel` object will contain a `members` field containing a collection of user IDs -- those who have joined the channel.

You would then have two options depending on your preferences:

1) Use [users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) to retrieve a list of all team members (including each user's presence) and narrow list of users down to those listed in the `members` field from above.

2) or, you could look up each user from that `members` field, one at a time using [users.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info).

Comment: can you tell, why `users.info` is needed?  with `users.list` there is said to be include presence data too, and is not that enough?

Comment: On very large teams, requesting `users.list` with presence can result in slow or error responses. It's also recommended your app only concern itself with the info it needs to function: if you only need presence information for a limited set of users, looking them up atomically is best.

Comment: @TaylorSingletary doesn't `members` give info of ACTIVE users only? why to compare with the list returned by `users.list`?

Comment: @Volatil3 `members` will include all active channel members, yes, but the active status is actually unrelated to `presence`.